# Excel: Creating random groups of items based on selection in table (exclusive & exhaustive groups)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with names in one column and boolean date selections in the others.

[image: Here is an image of what the data could look like.]

---

You can assume that:

- Each name and date is unique
- Each name has at least one date selection

I am trying to create random groups from that table such that:

1. Each group has an assigned date and clear list of member names
2. Group size is limited by minimum and maximum values
3. Each name belongs to exactly one group
4. If possible, the dates assigned to groups do not overlap

---

An example for valid groups of size 2-3 for the above data (see image) would be:

- Group A - Tuesday: Alice, Bob
- Group B - Wednesday: Charlie, Frank
- Group C - Thursday: Destin, Eric

Any help is appreciated, I do not even know where to start with this problem.

Comment: Did you try to approach this with, e.g., the excel solver? How big is your problem in terms of different names?

Comment: @carl The problem is not terribly large, but just a little too big and cumbersome to do manually (think 20-40). I have not tried the solver, I am not even sure how that approach could work. Would you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is an optimization problem that also seems to be somewhat related to the famous "Knapsack problem". You could try to solve this problem, e.g., with the `Excel Solver` as outlined below. There may be other options, but the Solver is relatively handy for such problems.

First, slightly tweak your data entries by setting x to 1 and the empty cells to an appropriately high value (penalty), e.g., 999. Your data will then look like this:

[image: data input]

As a next step, you need to create a second array that specifies your changing variable cells. In other words, you want to create an array that will allow you to optimize your mapping since you want to assign each person to a specific group. This array looks similar to your initial array of names and I have assumed that your days (=5) reflect 5 different groups. Depending on your problem, you may need to change this. You will also need to add a total row that simply reflects the sum of each group, and an allocated column that indicates whether or not a person has been assigned to a group. Since this is an optimization problem, you need an objective that you want to optimize, and in this case that is simply the minimum sumproduct (you might need to change the ; in the formula to ,) of the mapping array and your input data. This works because you constrain the mapping array to binary numbers (see below in the context of setting up the Solver), where 1 indicates that you were selected in a particular group, and 0 indicates that you were not selected. The selection (i.e., mapping array) is then multiplied by your input array, which imposes a large penalty if you are selected in a group that does not match your preference:

[image: array to be optimized]

In a next step you have to set up the Solver itself. To do this, go to the tab `Data` -> `Solver`. Your objective is to minimize the sum product in cell `$P$2`. Your changing variable cells are located in the range `I2:M7`, and you need to add the following three constraints via the button `Add`:
[image: solver parameters]

1: your range `I2:M7` can only take binary values (`Cell Reference: $I$2:$M$7 bin Constraint: binary`),

2: you need to have at least one person in each group (`Cell Reference: $I$8:$M$8 >= Constraint: 1`). At the moment I have not constrained the maximum number of people in each group, but you could easily add this constraint,

3: each person is included in exactly one group (`Cell Reference: $N$2:$N$7 = Constraint: 1`).

Once everything is set up, you can hit the `Solve` button and your problem will be optimized and you will be informed if a solution to your optimization problem has been found:

[image: solver result]

Comment: Thank you, I think this approach could work with a couple of minor tweaks to suit my data.